# File upload does not work in PHP on Apache Server

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to upload an image file onto a Web server running on a Raspberry.
The image should be uploaded through a form and forwarded to a PHP script.
I checked if the folders are set to the proper permissions and it seems OK.
Code seems to run without a problem.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="./php/fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   Wähle eine Datei aus: <br> <input name="datei" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Sende Datei" />
</form>
```

The file selected in this form will be sent to this script:

```
<?php
$upload_dir = "/uploads/";
$file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$file_filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$targeted_Upload = $upload_dir . $file_filename . "." . $file_extension;
$temp_file = $_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"];

var_dump($upload_dir);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($targeted_Upload);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($file_filename);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($file_extension);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($temp_file);
echo "<br>";

if(file_exists($targeted_Upload)){
    echo "file exists... renaming";
    echo "<br>";
    $newName = $upload_dir . $file_filename;
    do{
        $newName = $newName . "_1";
    }while(file_exists(($newName . "." . $file_extension)));

    $targeted_Upload = $newName . "." . $file_extension;

    echo "file was renamed to " . $targeted_Upload;
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($targeted_Upload);
    echo "<br>";
}

if ($_FILES["datei"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
}

echo"$targeted_Upload";
echo "<br>";

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $targeted_Upload)){
    echo "<br>File was Uploaded" . "<a href=\"$targeted_Upload\">$targeted_Upload</a>";
}else{
    echo "I have no clue what happened";
}
?>
```

When I execute the script the output on the page is as following

```
string(9) "/uploads/"
string(16) "/uploads/ken.jpg"
string(3) "ken"
string(3) "jpg"
string(14) "/tmp/phpv0JAu1"
/uploads/ken.jpg
I have no clue what happened
```

Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong or what went wrong?

Comment: Does the web server user have permissions to write to `/uploads` ?

Comment: "drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 17 15:14 uploads"
yes.

Comment: yes you have all the permissions needed for storing document in the folder. actually more than required

Comment: Yeah i know that. I did that on purpose so that I don't have to watch the permissions for now.

Comment: if this line is false then something really wrong in the file path-     `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $targeted_Upload)){`  Do one thing just hard-code file path for testing and check

Comment: Well i printed out pretty much everything i needed: `$temp_file` would be `/tmp/phpv0JAu1` here and `$targeted_Upload` is `/uploads/ken.jpg` here

Comment: "Do one thing just hard-code file path for testing and check" will do that give me a sec

Comment: Hardcoding the path didn't do anything there still is an error while uploading

Comment: Did you mean to use `"/uploads/";` i.e. `root folder/uploads` or should that be `"uploads\"` i.e. the folder below where you are which is probably the DocumentRoot folder.

Comment: okay then please see my suggested solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File will be stored in temporary location-
Give full path of the upload location.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/project_name/$targeted_Upload)) {
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
   echo "File was not uploaded";
}
```

Comment: It really seems to be a problem with the path. I will see what i have to change. Thanks for the help.

Comment: okay changing the relative path to the absolute did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with your upload path. if PHP script and uploads is in the same directrory then you should use dot[.] for current directory

```
$upload_dir = "./uploads/";
```

You can check upload error.

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $targeted_Upload)){
    echo "<br>File was Uploaded" . "<a href=\"$targeted_Upload\">$targeted_Upload</a>";
}else{
    echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["datei"]["error"];
}
```

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE = Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE = Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL = Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially
>   uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE = Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR = Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE = Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION = Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file
>   upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused
>   the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with
>   phpinfo() may help.

Comment: Yup had to use the absolute path

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Use the absolute file path in the destination parameter in `move_uploaded_file()`.

   Edit `move_uploaded_file` and append the destination parameter with `__DIR__.'/'.`:
   `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, __DIR__.'/'.$targeted_Upload)){ ... }`
2. Make sure that the directory `/uploads` is created, and that the web server user have permissions to write to it.

Comment: as i said to the others, it really was the absolute path that was missing

Answer (score 1):

I had permission issue to the target folder(In case the path is correct).If anyone by chance having this issue, please give permission to the folder using the below command in the terminal.

```
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/upload/folder
```

Please note I am using Ubuntu 18.04LTS.